# Adding a web service for office add-in using ASP.NET web api

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, ms-word, office365, office-addins

I have followed [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2013/06/10/create-a-web-service-for-an-app-for-office-using-the-asp-net-web-api/) to add web service to my office 365 add-in. But when I execute the ajax script which send the request it always end up in .fail statement. I can not see program execute even a single line in the controller class or Global.asax or webApiConfig class.

This is my javasript code snippet

```
function GetStyles(ooxml) {
    var data = {
        xml: ooxml
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/GetStyles',
        type: 'GET',
        data: data,
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    }).done(function (data) {
        showNotification(data.Status, data.Message);
    }).fail(function (status) {
        showNotification('Error', 'Could not communicate with the server.');
    }).always(function () {
        // $('.disable-while-sending').prop('disabled', false);
    });
}
```

this is the controller class

```
public class WriterController : ApiController
{
    public class FeedbackRequest
    {
        public string xml;
    }

    public class FeedBackResponse
    {
        public string status;
        public string message;
    }

    [HttpGet()]
    public FeedBackResponse GetStyles(FeedbackRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            return new FeedBackResponse
            {
                status = "success",
                message = "success success",
            };
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new FeedBackResponse
            {
                status = "error",
                message = "error error",
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Check the value of `status` in `.fail`. It probably contains very useful information.

Answer (score 2):

Just looking at the code, nothing jumps out as clearly wrong. But I can give you some advice on how to go about debugging this.

First, try to debug this outside the context of an Office Add-in. There is nothing "add-in"-y about it. So just launch your html page in Internet Explorer, or better yet, make the request using Fiddler. The result should shed the light on what is going wrong within the Add-in.

Comment: Michael Zlatkovsky :Thanks for the advice. I got the response as

{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:44331/api/GetStyles'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'GetStyles'."}.

But you can see there is a method called "GetStyles" in my controller class. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You mentioned "Global.asax or webApiConfig class."  What about them?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found the problem. The controller name should be begin with controller method name we suupose to send the reequest. For an example in here controller method we used to send the request is GetStyles. So Controller name should be GetStylesController. This solved my problem

Comment: Glad you found the answer!